# Synching WPF animations with data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, animation, synchronization

I have a zoom control from WPF Extensions toolkit that zooms in and out smoothly using an animation and pans a canvas smoothly as well. When I've bound my data to some of the controls' properties (such as Zoom and TranslateX / TranslateY) the UI is very sluggish and takes time to update.

My question is this - Is there a way to temporary disable the binding so that the animations and transitions will occur smoothly and only after they're finished my databinding will occur? I'm guessing there is such a way but I could not find out how...

Thanks for the help folks!

Code:

```
<Controls:ZoomControl Style="{DynamicResource ZoomControlStyle1}" x:Name="zoomControl" Zoom="{Binding MapModel.ZoomFactor, Mode=OneWayToSource}" 
                      TranslateX="{Binding MapModel.CenterXLocation, Mode=OneWayToSource}" TranslateY="{Binding MapModel.CenterYLocation, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
```

Comment: I would say, that you don't gain a lot out of it. Binding is quite fast in wpf and i'm almost certain, that this is not your problem. Instead i would say your content in the panel is render heavy. Or you do something else expensive when setting your bound position. Are you only setting the values you are binding or is there more stuff in the background going on?

Comment: You are correct about the content being heavy - it's a canvas loaded with many `UIElement` objects. When the OnPropertyChanged event handler is fired, I'm running a small function that calculates some values that are reflected in the application's UI

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess: Use a one-way binding, so that the changing of Zoom or TranslateX isn't reflected back to your binding-source.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't help. I'm currently using a OneWayToSource binding (I've added a code snippet to demonstrate) and it's still slow

Comment: @JonathanPerry: Other way round again :-) Use `OneWay` instead of `OneWayToSource`.

Comment: @JonathanPerry: `OneWayToSource` is a binding from the binding source (your control) to the binding target (your property) where the value of the target is written to the source, `OneWay` means a binding where the value is written from the source to the target. It means the direction of data transfer. When you choose `OneWayToSource` every change of the TranslateX is written back to your property during the animation.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. So I basically should update the TranslateX value only on MouseUp and not during animation?

Comment: @JonathanPerry: You **can** have a binding to TranlsateX, but it has to be `OneWay`, so the value isn't written back to your property during the animation.